# Using ArcMap to calculate percent for each pixel

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, land-cover, pixel, land-use

I am using ArcMap.

I have a land use file in TIFF format with 10 meter resolution. I would like to know in 30*30 square meter of my file how can I calculate which percent of each pixel of my file is occupied by urban area, water, trees (all in percent, for instance: 75% for urban, 30% water).

Comment: So 5% of the urban is under water?

Comment: No there is nothing under water. I want to know in each pixel  of my file (30*30), what percent is for urban category and what percent is for green are or water. I should say 70 % for urban and 30% for water

Comment: Are you using ArcGIS Pro or ArcMap?  What have you tried with whichever you want to ask about in this particular question?

Comment: @PolyGeo I am using ArcMap. I could only resize my .tif file from 10m to 30 meter resolution. After this step I did not know how to calculate what percentage of a pixel is occupied by each land use category(for instance what percentage of a pixel is occupied by building, or water)

Comment: Are the water bodies is 25% or the urban is 70%?

Comment: @Yogi it was an example!

Comment: Convert your tiff to an integer GRID and open the attribute table to get the pixel counts by value.  Do the math.